# Ionic 3 Push notification

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to implement push notification in my ionic app. for the same I am using following plugin

```
ionic cordova  plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=12341234 --save
```

When I am running following command

```
ionic serve --lab
```

Application is running in browser but when I am trying to build for android using following command

ionic cordova build android

I am getting following exeception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
    * Where:
    Script '\android\phonegap-plugin-push\com-push.gradle' line: 38

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
        > For input string: "+"
```

Comment: can you look at any dependency which have with `+`?

Comment: cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+